# How to call a Pentaho cde dashboard with parameters list hidden using post request?

Tags: post, parameters, request, pentaho

I am using Pentaho Bi server 5.3. And created a simple Dashbboard with Date Input Parameter.

I am able to access the Dashboard using the below link

http://localhost:8080/pentaho/api/repos/%3Ahome%3Aadmin%3ALanding.wcdf/generatedContent?date_s=15-08-2015

At the Pentaho end, created a custom parameter
    `date_s=Dashboards.getQueryParameter('date_s');`

Now I am trying to access the Dashboard inside a webapplication 
using the form request html code.
When i click on the submit button I am able to see the Dashboard,but the date select component is empty, `date_s` value is not passed to the dashboard select component.

How to send the parameter via post request header ?
At the `pentaho` end what all changes I need to do to access this Dashboard via 'Post Request' ?
and also please provide some inputs to integrate `Pentaho Dashboards` inside a webapplication ?

Comment: <form action="http://localhost:8080/pentaho/api/repos/%3Ahome%3Aadmin%3ALanding.wcdf/generatedContent" method="post" target="_blank">
 <INPUT type=hidden name=userid value="guest">
  <INPUT type=hidden name=password value="abc123"> 
  <INPUT type=hidden name=date_s value="15-08-2015">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>      form request code

Comment: Have you accomplished your task? I'm facing the exact same issue and can't find a solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the parameter's name in the "Listeners" in the Advanced Properties of the select component.
Could you put a snapshot of the select component?

Comment: the date_s=Dashboards.getQueryParameter('date_s'); can contain just on value. Whay do you want to show just one value in a select component?

Comment: I have a requirement to call this pentaho dashboard inside a webapplication through post request and send the parameter through post request header. So I am showing single value in the select.component                                             Could u pls let me know how to read parameter value from the post request header in pentaho cde?